# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error with Struts 2 file upload

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs, struts2

I have followed [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/) link to create a sample file upload application with Struts2. The sample works great. But when I am trying to upload an image using AJAX I get the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/HeeloServer/userImage.action. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is the code to my action class. Note that I am using the response.addHeader() method to all (*) origins. I have similar code at other actions where there is no problem, and get this error only when doing a Struts2 file upload using AJAX.

```
package actions;

import java.io.File;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletResponseAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware {
    private File userImage;
    private String userImageContentType;
    private String userImageFileName;
    private String email;

    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("inside file upload action");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        try {
            String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "photos/";
            System.out.println("Server path: " + filePath);
            System.out.println("Image to be uploaded " + userImageFileName);
            System.out.println("Email" + email);
            File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);
            FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return INPUT;
        }

        return SUCCESS;

    }

    public File getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    public void setUserImage(File userImage) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }

    public String getUserImageContentType() {
        return userImageContentType;
    }

    public void setUserImageContentType(String userImageContentType) {
        this.userImageContentType = userImageContentType;
    }

    public String getUserImageFileName() {
        return userImageFileName;
    }

    public void setUserImageFileName(String userImageFileName) {
        this.userImageFileName = userImageFileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response){
        this.response = response;
      }

      public HttpServletResponse getServletResponse(){
        return response;
      }




    private HttpServletResponse response;
    public HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }






}
```

Comment: Cross site scripting. Different ports.

Comment: @mituw16 I know that, that is why I am trying to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin with a value of * to all cross site requests. Now, before you go and tell me how insecure that is, its just for testing purposes right now.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to. That's a browser security feature, no server side code would be able to change that.

Comment: This is possible. I am doing exactly this at other places with the same application. I am doing a mobile app which accesses these URLs. This is my reference which I have used to make it work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: After removing the getResponse, setResponse and getServletResponse from the action class did the trick for me. The only method for setting is the overloaded setServletResponse for ServletResponse interface.

Comment: @mituw16 you are right mate when you say its a browser security feature to disable cross site attacks, but it is possible if the server or the server response allows that.